# How I connect logstash with kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash

My kafka is able to connect to kafkaJS or another external network when I try to link it with logstash, but I am unable to create a connection with the broker. My Broker might not be available.

this is my code for logstash.conf

```
input {

  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9094, localhost:9095, localhost:9096, localhost:9097"
    codec => json
    topics => ["log-javaapp"]
    group_id => "logstash_group"  
    consumer_threads => 1
    decorate_events => false
    jaas_path => "/usr/share/logstash/config/jaas.conf"
    
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "(?<session_id>[A-Z0-9]{32}-[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+)" ]
    named_captures_only => true
  }

}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://172.26.0.2:9200"]
    index => "test-kafka-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    cacert => './config/certs/http_ca.crt'
    user => 'elastic'
    password => 'Sb9yeV9BrQZdwfhdVnm4'
    ssl_certificate_verification => true
  }
}
```

jaas.conf

```
 KafkaClient {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useTicketCache=true
  renewTicket=true
  serviceName="kafka";
 };
```

and this is my log result

````
2023-12-25 11:00:53 [2023-12-25T04:00:53,707][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][7c95c0e83c6f7db9faf577b355546730a07b8355844226a7d2fbe24b9adbc6a1] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash_group] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-12-25 11:00:53 [2023-12-25T04:00:53,707][WARN ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][7c95c0e83c6f7db9faf577b355546730a07b8355844226a7d2fbe24b9adbc6a1] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash_group] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9094) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-12-25 11:00:53 [2023-12-25T04:00:53,707][WARN ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][7c95c0e83c6f7db9faf577b355546730a07b8355844226a7d2fbe24b9adbc6a1] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash_group] Bootstrap broker localhost:9094 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2023-12-25 11:00:53 [2023-12-25T04:00:53,807][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][7c95c0e83c6f7db9faf577b355546730a07b8355844226a7d2fbe24b9adbc6a1] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash_group] Node -2 disconnected.
2023-12-25 11:00:53 [2023-12-25T04:00:53,807][WARN ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][7c95c0e83c6f7db9faf577b355546730a07b8355844226a7d2fbe24b9adbc6a1] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash_group] Connection to node -2 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9095) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-12-25 11:00:53 [2023-12-25T04:00:53,807][WARN ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][7c95c0e83c6f7db9faf577b355546730a07b8355844226a7d2fbe24b9adbc6a1] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash_group] Bootstrap broker localhost:9095 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected
2023-12-25 11:00:53 [2023-12-25T04:00:53,807][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][7c95c0e83c6f7db9faf577b355546730a07b8355844226a7d2fbe24b9adbc6a1] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash_group] Node -3 disconnected.
2023-12-25 11:00:53 [2023-12-25T04:00:53,807][WARN ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][7c95c0e83c6f7db9faf577b355546730a07b8355844226a7d2fbe24b9adbc6a1] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash_group] Connection to node -3 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9096) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-12-25 11:00:53 [2023-12-25T04:00:53,807][WARN ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][7c95c0e83c6f7db9faf577b355546730a07b8355844226a7d2fbe24b9adbc6a1] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash_group] Bootstrap broker localhost:9096 (id: -3 rack: null) disconnected
2023-12-25 11:00:53 [2023-12-25T04:00:53,907][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][7c95c0e83c6f7db9faf577b355546730a07b8355844226a7d2fbe24b9adbc6a1] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash_group] Node -4 disconnected.
2023-12-25 11:00:53 [2023-12-25T04:00:53,907][WARN ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][7c95c0e83c6f7db9faf577b355546730a07b8355844226a7d2fbe24b9adbc6a1] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash_group] Connection to node -4 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9097) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2023-12-25 11:00:53 [2023-12-25T04:00:53,908][WARN ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][7c95c0e83c6f7db9faf577b355546730a07b8355844226a7d2fbe24b9adbc6a1] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash_group] Bootstrap broker localhost:9097 (id: -4 rack: null) disconnected
2023-12-25 11:00:53 [2023-12-25T04:00:53,908][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][7c95c0e83c6f7db9faf577b355546730a07b8355844226a7d2fbe24b9adbc6a1] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash_group] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-12-25 11:00:53 [2023-12-25T04:00:53,908][WARN ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][7c95c0e83c6f7db9faf577b355546730a07b8355844226a7d2fbe24b9adbc6a1] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash_group] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9094) could not be established. Broker may not be available.```
````